# Why is my count function so off in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of members and a table of listings.  I want to fetch a list of members and get the number of listings that they have posted.  For some reason, my current query has been returning a value of 30 when it is supposed to be 6.  Am I completely misunderstanding joins or the count function right now?

Here is my query.  And yes, m.user_id is supposed to be that and not m.member_id like it shows in the listings table.

```
SELECT m.user_id AS id, m.group_id, m.email_address, m.display_name,  m.status, 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date) AS join_date, m.about, m.facebook_url, 
       m.twitter_url, m.address, m.region_id, m.city, m.zip, m.avatar_id,
       g.group_id, g.title AS group_title, p.group_id, p.context, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.context) AS permissions,
       r.region_id, r.title AS region_title,
       a.attachment_id, a.file_path AS avatar_path,
       l.member_id, COUNT(l.member_id) AS total_listings
FROM users AS m 
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON m.group_id = g.group_id
LEFT JOIN permissions AS p ON m.group_id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN regions AS r ON m.region_id = r.region_id
LEFT JOIN attachments AS a ON m.avatar_id = a.attachment_id
LEFT JOIN listings AS l ON m.user_id = l.member_id
WHERE m.user_id = 1
GROUP BY m.user_id
LIMIT 1
```

Here is a screenshot of the listings table so you can see that there are only 6 listings with a member id of 1.  These are the only listing rows in the database.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to count after grouping. You are counting the total rows which include the duplicates due to the joins. Try something like

```
SELECT x.*, COUNT(total_listings) as count FROM (
    SELECT m.user_id AS id, m.group_id, m.email_address, m.display_name, m.status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date) AS join_date, m.about, m.facebook_url, m.twitter_url, m.address, m.region_id, m.city, m.zip, m.avatar_id,
    g.group_id, g.title AS group_title, p.group_id, p.context, GROUP_CONCAT(p.context) AS permissions,
    r.region_id, r.title AS region_title,
    a.attachment_id, a.file_path AS avatar_path,
    l.member_id, l.member_id AS total_listings
FROM users AS m 
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON m.group_id = g.group_id
LEFT JOIN permissions AS p ON m.group_id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN regions AS r ON m.region_id = r.region_id
LEFT JOIN attachments AS a ON m.avatar_id = a.attachment_id
LEFT JOIN listings AS l ON m.user_id = l.member_id
WHERE m.user_id = 1
GROUP BY m.user_id) x
```

Comment: If your original query works, I honestly don't see why the above would give you that error.

Comment: I suggest simplifying the query and removing all the columns in the select except the `l.member_id AS total_listings`. Once you get that to work, add the columns back in to find where the problem exists. If the problem exists with the shortened query - then it is with one of the two joins and will help you narrow the problem.

Comment: Oddly enough, I have discovered that adding my group_concat function is when the number changes from 6 to 30.  Any idea why this would happen?  This is happening while using the query without your addition of the outer select statement.

Comment: When I use the addition of your outer select statement, the total listings value becomes 1.... even if I remove the group_concat again.

Comment: You want to group on a listings field which will give a unique listing for the member / user id (not on the user id). Then you will get the correct number of records.You may not need the outer select then as well. If you can't figure it out, post your structure and the sample data for each table that should yield 6 rows. In the evening late tonight I will be able to help.